# AngularJS unit testing - Class Undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write some basic tests for some controllers I have. I pass in some services that use other services. One service that is passed in, "catalog service" user a service called "metrics service". This metrics calls a Helper that is declared at the top of the file, and it's being pulled from a package defined in my dependencies section of my Config file. The code works/builds fine but the tests says that this Helper is undefined. What am I missing here?

This is the test

```
 beforeEach(module("photonControllersPreSession"));

  var $controller;
  var $rootScope;
  var $scope;
  var createController;

  var $window;
  var $location;
  var loggerService;
  var controller;

  beforeEach(
    angular.mock.module( function(
      _$controller_,
      _$rootScope_,
      _$window_,
      _$location_,
      _loggerService_
    ) {

      $controller = _$controller_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $window = _$window_;
      $location = _$location_;
      loggerService = _loggerService_;
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      controller = $controller("CatalogController", {
        $scope: $scope,
        $location: $location,
        $window: $window,
        loggerService: loggerService
      });


    })
  );
```

This is the service (which is used by logger service) that calls the undefined Helper

```
declare var HelperUtils;

export class MetricsService {

public static $inject: Array<string> = ["$rootScope", "$window", Constants.Photon.SERVICE_LOGGER];
private ubmHelper;
private dimensions: Array<any> = [];
private metricList = null;
private TAG = "MetricsService";
private trackingScopes: any = {};
private isEditing = false;

constructor(protected $rootScope, protected  $window:Interfaces.IPhotonWindowObject, protected loggerService: LoggerService, protected hiddenBrowserDetectionService: Services.HiddenBrowserDetectionService) {
  let ubmOptions = {
    idleInterval: 3000,
    submitInterval: 5000,
    header: {},
    logLevel: HelperUtils.LogLevelEnum.INFO,
    properties: {
      test : accountID
    }
  };
```

My karma config is below

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  "use strict";

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: "../",

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    // as well as any additional frameworks (requirejs/chai/sinon/...)
    frameworks: [
      "jasmine",
      "karma-typescript"
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "vendor/angular/angular.js",
      "vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.js",
      "vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js",
      "vendor/angular-messages/angular-messages.js",
      "vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
      "vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js",
      "vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
      "vendor/angular-touch/angular-touch.js",
      "vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
      //"app/photon-app.js",
      "app/scripts/commons/providers/ui-notification.js",
      "app/scripts/commons/constants.ts",
      "app/constants-global.ts",
      "app/scripts/commons/interfaces/*.ts",
      "app/scripts/commons/factories/*.ts",
      "app/scripts/commons/services/*.ts",
      "app/**/*.ts",
      "test/specs/**/*.ts",
      {
        pattern: '**/*.js.map',
        included: false
      }
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
      "photon/**/*.d.ts",
      "app/scripts/commons/services/message-service.ts" //TODO: please add this servcie back after basic sannity test are passing
    ],

    //This is neede to load all *spec.ts 
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
    },


    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noLib": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "target": "es5",
        // or es3, es6
        "declaration": false
        // Not compile .d.ts files

      },
      "exclude": [
        "photon/**/*.d.ts",
        "app/scripts/commons/services/message-service.ts" //TODO: please add this servcie back after basic sannity test are passing
      ],
      "include": [
        "app/scripts/commons/constants.ts",
        "app/constants-global.ts",
        "app/scripts/commons/interfaces/*.ts",
        "app/scripts/commons/factories/*.ts",
        "app/scripts/commons/services/*.ts",
        "app/**/*.ts"
        //"test/specs/**/*.ts"
      ]
    },

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    browsers: [
      "Chrome"
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
      "karma-chrome-launcher",
      "karma-jasmine",
      "karma-coverage",
      "karma-junit-reporter",
      "karma-typescript"
    ],

    reporters: ["progress", "junit", "coverage"],

    preprocessors: {
      "app/**/*.ts": ['karma-typescript']
    },
    bundlerOptions: {
      transforms: [
        require("karma-typescript-es6-transform")()
      ]
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [{
        type: 'cobertura',
        dir: 'coverage',
        file: 'coverage.xml'
      }, {
        type: 'html',
        dir: 'coverage'
      }, {
        type: 'text-summary'
      }]
    },

    junitReporter: {
      //outputDir: "../build/brazil-unit-tests", // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      //outputDir: "../build/brazil-unit-tests/test-results.xml", // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: "../build/brazil-unit-tests/test-results.xml", // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: "PhotonPortal", // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {} // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
    },

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


  });
```

Comment: Can you publish your Karma configuration file?

I think the issue is that HelperUtils is a JavaScript global, but the file that declares isn't loaded by karma.

Also what do you mean by Config file?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking but the service file that declares it should be covered by "app/scripts/commons/services/*.ts" and I mean my package Config file where all the dependencies are listed.

Comment: @Josephhooper Could you please also provide an exact error message you got?

Comment: @LuninRoman ReferenceError: HelperUtils is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It is just some notes for your consideration and not an answer. Speaking about unit-tests, the point is to test controller/service/filter or whatever *independently*, that's why it called *unit* tests. There is other type of tests, called *E2E*, which is `End to End`, which covers all code together, but this is the whole other story.

So I would suggest you to rewrite your code like so

```
 beforeEach(
    angular.mock.module( function(
      _$controller_,
      _$rootScope_,
      _$window_,
      _$location_,
    ) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $window = _$window_;
      $location = _$location_;
      loggerService = jasmine.createSpyObj('loggerService', ['method1', 'method2']);
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      controller = $controller("CatalogController", {
        $scope: $scope,
        $location: $location,
        $window: $window,
        loggerService: loggerService
      });
    })

    it('should test some CatalogController method', function () {
        CatalogController.someMethod();

        expect(loggerService.method1).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(loggerService.method1).toHaveBeenCalledWith('whatever');
    });
  );
```

So as you see, I put `loggerService` mock, where `method1`, `method2` are methods, used in `CatalogController`. And this is what I talking about - unit test is just to check that `loggerService.method1` has been called in some particular moment, you don't need to check what exactly `method1` or `method2` has done, it is what you should test in `loggerService` test, but it is not a matter of `CatalogController` test. But still, I'm not sure what is the problem with `HelperUtils` being undefined.